# What is wrong with my prime filtering code? It won't return the proper list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, primes

I wrote a function `filter_primes` that is supposed to (aptly) filter out prime numbers from a given list and output a new list of just the primes. When I run this example I get>>> [9].
My brain is boggled. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
n = 2

def is_prime(num):
  global n
  if num%n != 0 and n<num:
    n = n + 1
    is_prime(num)
  elif n == num:
    return True
  else:
    return False

def filter_primes(list1):
  list2 = []
  for i in list1:
    if is_prime(i):
      list2.append(i)

  print(list2)


filter_primes([7, 9, 3, 9, 10, 11, 27])
```

Comment: Setting `n` globally is part of your issue. When you call is_prime(7), n becomes 7. When you then call `is_prime(3)`, `n>3`, so it returns false.  set `n=2` as the first line of the function, get rid of `global n` and the `n=2` outside of the function. See if that fixes the issue.

Comment: try googling python + Sieve of Eratosthenes ... you're bound to get some hits on SO. use that.

Comment: Problems are a missing `return` and using `global`

Comment: @user1558604: That won't work with the recursive approach they took here. Either pass n to is_prime, or get rid of the recursion.

Comment: @Junuxx, good call. Didn't notice the recursion, I'd do it in a while loop if it was me.

Comment: Also, @MissAri, consider that you only need to check up to n<sqrt(num) instead of up to num.

Comment: Oh, weird! I started without global n and just had n = 2 as the first line...but in that case it ran forever and wasn't iterating

Comment: @Junuxx ohhh! thank you

Comment: You aren't returning the return value of the recursive call: `return is_prime(num)`. But don't use recursion at all here; use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `is_prime` function. Since you are doing it recursively, you want to separate it into:

- Handle the base cases:

  1. You find an `n` that evenly divides `num`, then `num` isn't prime
  2. You end up with an `n` bigger than `num`, then `num` is prime
- Otherwise, call your function recursively with `n+1` and `return` that value.

One way to get around using the global n (which then gets overwritten each time a new larger is used), is to have is_prime have a default starting value for n)
For example,

```
def is_prime(num, n=2):
  if n >= num:  # This could be made into sqrt(num) if you're trying to optimize this
      return True
  if num % n == 0:
      return False
  return is_prime(num, n+1)
```

Comment: I like how you made it work using OP's recursive approach rather than completely rewriting it. This provides an opportunity to learn about the limits of recursion when she attempts, say, `is_prime(1000001)`, rather than just being told not to do something.

Answer (score 1):

The way I tackled this was to open the code up in an IDE (IntelliJ), and then step through the code line by line using an intergrated debugger. This will help you visualize what is going on. Else try printing out variables inside the function.

You first problem is that you are using `global n`. This works perfectly fine for the first number `7`, but this number doesn't get reset for the second number `9`. Thus what is happening is that `is_prime(9)` is only testing against division of `8` (which is why it returns true)

This could potentually be done in a loop rather than using recursion, but since you are using recursion, `n` (as internal state) can be handled by passing this as a function parameter with a default. This will reset n for each top level call for n.

Also as you are recursively calling `is_prime()`, you need `return is_prime()` to ensure the boolean returned from the top of the stack gets returned when you unwind back to the bottom of the stack for the original caller.

Your code accidently worked for `is_prime(9)` because your logic was only testing for 8, thus could return without recusion.

Here is working code:

```py
def is_prime(num, n=2):
    if num % n != 0 and n < num:
        n = n + 1
        return is_prime(num, n)
    elif n == num:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def filter_primes(list1):
    list2 = []
    for i in list1:
        if is_prime(i):
            list2.append(i)
    return list2


print( filter_primes([7, 9, 3, 9, 10, 11, 27]) )
```

```
$ primes.py
[7, 3, 11]
```

Also you might find it intresting to do a little reading up on `prime number search algorithms`.

A few simple optimizations:

- Except for 2, all prime numbers are odd (so you can return False instantly)
- Sieve of Eratosthenes extends this further
- Technically you only need to search upto `sqrt(num)`
- Read up on `memoization` (aka dynamic programming), as you can cache results from previous function calls
- Add python type hints and write documention for your functions (your future self will thank you when you return the code in a month)

Consider a new usecase:

- generate the entire sequence of prime numbers (you will start to notice performance issues here)
- Add a timer, or use a profiler inside your IDE. Compare how fast the code runs, especially for large numbers. Do these suggested optimizations speed things up?

Comment: @James_McGuigan thank you! This is so clarifying and helpful. Thank you so much. I will definitely read up on the prime algorithms. It was my first time thinking about finding primes with programming, and I realized what a big idea it is..

Comment: @MissAri There is an entire section of mathematics called Number Theory, which deals with the extended question of determining the properties numbers in relationship to each other. This has kept mathemeticians busy for centuries and even millenia. Now we have the age of internet computers, we have the Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search [https://www.mersenne.org/], and they managed to find and prove that 2^(82,589,933)-1 is a prime number!

Comment: @James_McGuigan....thank you!! I have wanted to study Number Theory. Now I have a good reason :)
One more question...I went through my original code step-by-step and realized that the global n was not getting reset -- big problem. I see now! However, passing the list:  [7, 9, 3, 9, 10, 11, 27] to filter_primes() should work for the first item, 7, and append it to the empty list. Then it should have also appended 9, as 9 would have passed the is_prime() test.
So why is it returning only [9] when I run my original code?

Comment: In your original code, you are using `global n` and happen to be testing `7` first. Thus the search space for `filter_primes(9)` is `[8, 9]`. Try stepping through the code using a debugger, and you will see that `n = 7; n += 1; n % 9 != 0; n += 1; n % 9 == 0; return [9]`